# Making colorbar tick labels a string above and below bar, remove ticks - Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, gradient, axis, colorbar

I am trying to reproduce the colorbar below for my chart. Specifically it is the string colorbar axis title (above and below the colorbar) that I am struggling with, the rest seems fine.

[image: desired colorbar]
Below is my current code:

```
    time_begin  = [1981, 1, 1, 0,0,0];
    time_end    = [2010,12,31,23,0,0];
    years       = (time_begin(1):time_end(1))';
    nyears      = length(years);
    TXx1 = randi(100, 288, 192, 30);
    lat = rand(192, 1);
    lon = rand(288, 1);
    time = rand(30,1);
    M = numel(lon);
    N = numel(lat);
    slope1 = zeros(M, N);
    intercept1 = zeros(M, N);
    T = numel(time);
    x = ([ones(T, 1) years]);
    for i = 1 : M
        for j = 1 : N
            y1 = squeeze(TXx1(i, j, :));
            c = regress(y1, x);
            intercept1(i, j) = c(1);
            slope1(i, j) = c(2);      
        end
    end
    TXx2 = randi(100, 288, 192, 30);
    slope2 = zeros(M, N);
    intercept2 = zeros(M, N);
    T = numel(time);
    x = ([ones(T, 1) years]);
    for i = 1 : M
        for j = 1 : N
            y2 = squeeze(TXx2(i, j, :));
            c = regress(y2, x);
            intercept2(i, j) = c(1);
            slope2(i, j) = c(2);      
        end
    end
    figure()
    set(gcf, 'color', 'w'); 
    temp = [slope1(:) slope2(:)];
    temp(temp == 0) = NaN;
    [Q,Qc] = hist3(temp,'Nbins',[100 100],'CDataMode','auto');
    Qx = cell2mat(Qc(1));
    Qy = cell2mat(Qc(2));
    Q = Q';
    Q = Q./trapz(Qy,trapz(Qx,Q,2));
    surf(Qx,Qy,Q,'FaceColor','interp','EdgeColor','none')
    grid off
    set(gca, 'Fontsize', 12, 'Fontweight', 'Bold'); %added
    cmap = jet(500);
    cmap(1,:) = [1,1,1];
    colormap(cmap);
    h=colorbar;
    set(h,'position',[.91 .34 .031 .475]) %[xposition yposition width height].
    set(get(h,'ylabel'),'string','Point density'); 
    set(h,'XTickLabel',{'Low',' ',' ',' ',' ','High',}); 
    view(0,90)
```

Here is my current colourbar:
[image: current colorbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
set(h,'XTickLabel',{'Low',' ',' ',' ',' ','High',});
```

with:

```
h.YTick = h.Limits;
h.YTickLabel = {'Low', 'High'};
```

This makes two tick-lines and two tick labels. By setting YTicks of the colorbar to its limits, the tick-lines get overlapped by colorbar boundary. So these get hidden and now there is no need to remove them.
However there is this `TickLength` property which can be used otherwise i.e.

```
h.TickLength = 0;
```

**Result:**

[image: result]